# How do I get number of rows between two Dates/Times in SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can get the number of rows between two `dates` and between two `times` in SQL database from my windows form application in c#?

[image: screenShot]

As shown in the screenshot (SQL database), and using the following query I am trying to get the number of rows between two certain `dates` and `times`:

For example: The dates/times starts from today at `13:00:00` until now.

```
int NumberOfRows;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= pcn1;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '" + DateTime.Today.AddHours(13).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + "'  ", con);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 NumberOfRows= dt.Rows.Count;
```

The problem is: when I execute this query under button click it shows error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value". When I change the query format from `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd` it works but it returns number of row = 0 (it should return 3) .

Anything I am doing wrong? Please help how to get the number of rows between certain dates/times as shown in the query.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid formatting.

Comment: you should be using parameters, not inline.  Additionally why are you `ToString`ing your `datetime`?  If you're comparing `datetime`s compare `datetime`s, not `datetime`s and `string`/`varchars`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of formatting the `DateTime` values and concatenating them into the query string just use parameters.

```
SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate";
command.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(13);
command.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '" + DateTime.Today.AddHours(13).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") + "'  ", con);
```

make changes in code as above and try.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateTime BETWEEN @from AND @to",con);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from",fromDate);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to",toDate);
```

`fromDat` and `toDate` are two DateTime objects;

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
string myScalarQuery = "select count(*) from TableName where WHERE DateTime BETWEEN @from AND @to";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myScalarQuery, myConnection);
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from",fromDate);
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to",toDate);

myCommand.Connection.Open();
int count = (int) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
myConnection.Close();
```